# how to manipulation null value 'Operator '+' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'DBNull'.'

Tags: vb.net

```
For a As Integer = 0 To dgv2.RowCount - 2
    dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value = dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value + dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(1).Value
Next
```

Comment: I need null value in my case and I dont know how to manipulate null value for + operation work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'DBNull'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948574/operator-is-not-defined-for-type-dbnull-and-type-dbnull)

Comment: @MilaniaNurR What should `dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value` be if one or both of the other cells are null?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `DBNull` to be interpreted as `0` in your calculation, you can use an `If()` (kind of the VB version of the ternary conditional operator) to conditionally resolve to that value.  So instead of this:

```
dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value
```

You would have something like this:

```
If(dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value = DBNull.Value, 0, dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value)
```

Which basically means "if the value from the database is null, use a zero, otherwise use the value from the database".

So the whole line might look like:

```
dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value = If(dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value = DBNull.Value, 0, dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value) + If(dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(1).Value = DBNull.Value, 0, dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(1).Value)
```

As an aside, since it's clear that this makes the line of code much longer and more difficult to read, abstracting this behind any sort of helper function or extension method where possible would be a great next step.

Comment: This appears to be a perfect example case for an extension method

Answer (score 0):

I used `TryParse` to check for null. Even if the parse fails `Cell0` and `Cell1` will be zero. I chose `Integer` but any numeric parse should work

```
    For a As Integer = 0 To dgv2.RowCount - 2
        Dim Cell0 As Integer
        Dim Cell1 As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(CStr(dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value), Cell0)
        Integer.TryParse(CStr(dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(1).Value), Cell1)
        dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(2).Value = Cell0 + Cell1
    Next
```